# Crear Campos a partir de una Estructura dinámica

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, dynamics-ax

> **Hola quiero hacer que una clase mediante un campo muestre campos algos asi como MiObjeto.campos.Nombre etc, pero que esto sea dinamico
> es decir pasarle a un metodo una estructura con los campos que yo
> quiero ejmplo:**
>
> MiObjeto.Select("cadena sql","MiTabla") <=== esa seria la
> forma de implementarlo MiObjeto.Campos.Nombre;
> MiObjeto.Campos.Apellido; MiObjeto.Campos.Edad;

```
 public struct SCampos
     {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
     }

 
 public void Select<T>(string SqlString, string TableName)
 {
             try
             {
                 //quitamos los espacios vacios del principio y fin pero nos importa el del principio si excistiece.
                 var sString = SqlString.Trim().Substring(0,6); //como solo queremos autorizar Select, esta tiene 6 letras
                 //
                 if (sString.ToLower() == "select")
                 {
                     Coneccion.Open();
                     Cmd = new MySqlCommand(SqlString, Coneccion);
                     Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                     Cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                     Da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
                     DataTable Dt = new DataTable(TableName);
                     Da.Fill(Dt);
                     _Dv = new DataView();
                     _Dv.Table = Dt;
                     Coneccion.Close();
```

> en T pasaría la estructura que quiera dependido con la tabla que voy a trabajar en la base de datos pero `introducir
> el código aquí lo que quiero resolver es que se me cargue cada registro
> del Dt en cada campo y esto mostrarlo como dije al principio, en una
> variable Campo que contenga los campos obtenidos por el Dt.
>
> Lo que quiero lograr es crear los campos de la tabla y que se me
> muestren como en el ejemplo. Si alguien me puede ayudar le estaré re
> agradecido quiero resolver esto que me tiene como loco...

Comment: no hagas a mano algo que ya esta hecho miles de veces.. revisa por ejemplo DAPPER... estas tratando de hacer un ORM y hay montones ya funcionando...

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta!! Voy a investigar